# Linear DE Calculus

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I just want to check if my answer is correct.

Solve the linear differential equation.

$(D^5–7D^4–31D^3+103D^2+150D–216)y = 0$

Factoring it out:

$(D-3)(D-1)(D+2)(D-9)(D+4)$

Finall, I got:

$Y=C_1e^x + C_2e^{-2x} + C_3e^{-4x} + C_4e^3x + C_5e^9x$

Is it correct?

Comment: What is D in your question?

Comment: @JanEerland an operator of differentiation, if I can hazard a guess.

Comment: Your solution is correct. Up to a typesetting ussue - it should be $e^{3x}$ and $e^{9x}$ in the last two terms.